# Running subsequent commands within python

Tags: python, subprocess

I would like to be able to call two (or more) commands within python but I would like to make sure that the first is finished before the second starts. Is that possible with `subprocess`? For example:

```
subprocess.call("script1 input1 > out", shell=True)
```

and when that command finishes:

```
subprocess.call("script2 out>out2", shell=True)
```

or is there a better way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A call to `subprocess.call` blocks until the command completes. From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call):

> Wait for command to complete, then return the `returncode` attribute.

A similar option that also waits for completion is [`subprocess.check_call`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call). The difference between `call` and `check_call` is that the latter raises an exception for a nonzero return code, whereas the former returns the return code for all cases.

Comment: @BrianCain Thank you for the suggestion. I have updated to answer to include information about `subprocess.check_call`.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html):

> Run the command described by *args*. Wait for command to complete, then return the `returncode` attribute.

To do it asynchronously (so that you *aren't* waiting) you would use `subprocess.Popen`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to reproduce a shell pipeline?

If so, then, adapting the [example from the python docs](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline), your example might become:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
p1 = Popen([script1, input1], stdout=PIPE)
p2 = Popen([script2], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
p1.stdout.close() # Allow p1 to receive a SIGPIPE if p2 exits.
output = p2.communicate()[0]
```